# How to install Vcredist_x86 before my custom script in MSI

Tags: windows-installer

I have an MSI which executes another process from the cutom script(which reqiures the VC++ redistributable package to run) So, I need to install VC redist which is a MSI based installer before my custom script in my MSI. I tried by changing the 'SEQ' attribute of VC redist to **InstallInitialize** and the 'SEQ' attribute of custom script to **InstallFiles**. But, things wont work. How to acheive this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a another MSI based installer running in InstallExecuteSequence, this is not supported by Windows Installer. You could have the custom action scheduled in InstallUISequence.

However, custom actions should not be generally used for installing other applications, for this most professional setup authoring tools offer a bootstrapper, that allows you to install the prerequisites, like your VCredist, before the MSI of the main installation is launched. What tool are you using to build the package?

Comment: Am using MakeMSI for building the package... Is it possible to use bootstrapping with MakeMSI?

Comment: I am not familiar with this tool, however I found this info: http://makemsi-manual.dennisbareis.com/bootstrapper_exe_programs.htm